# Spring boot different in hibernate vs eclipselink

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, eclipselink

I'm trying to change from Hibernate to Eclipselink as Jpa provider for spring boot. However, I'm seeing some difference in behaviour between the two.

Eclipselink Configuration

```
package com.test.test2;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class EclipselinkJpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

protected EclipselinkJpaConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties 
    properties, ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager) {
    super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager);
}

@Override
protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
    return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Override
protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "false");
    return map;
}

}
```

Controller

```
package com.test.test2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController 
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
PersonService personService;

@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(personService.helloWorld(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("/createNewPerson")
public ResponseEntity<Person> createNewPerson() {
    Person res = personService.createNewPerson();
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("/updatePerson/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Person> updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Person res = personService.updatePerson(id);
    personService.transAnnotation();
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

Service

```
package com.test.test2;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PersonService {

@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;

public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

public Person createNewPerson () {
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    newPerson.setFirstName("firstName");
    newPerson.setLastName("lastName");
    return personRepository.save(newPerson);
}

public Person updatePerson(Long id) {
    Optional<Person> personOP = personRepository.findById(id);
    if (personOP.isPresent()) {
        Person person = personOP.get();
        person.setFirstName("Update Name");
    }

    return null;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void transAnnotation () {

}
}
```

Repository

```
package com.test.test2;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

Eclipselink behavior
When calling /updatePerson/{id} api, person.firstName is updated to db without calling personRepoitory.save() if the next method is tagged with @Transactional.
As spring repository itself is transactional, even calling a personRepository.findAll() will commit and firstName is updated to db.

Logs

> 2021-11-24 12:01:06.264  INFO 2868 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
> 2021-11-24 12:01:06.269  INFO 2868 --- [           main] com.test.test2.Test2Application          : Started Test2Application in 1.966 seconds (JVM running for 2.227)
> 2021-11-24 12:01:12.689  INFO 2868 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2021-11-24 12:01:12.689  INFO 2868 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2021-11-24 12:01:12.689  INFO 2868 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
> [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-11-24 12:01:12.741--ServerSession(2122837918)--Connection(555991754)--SELECT ID, first_name, last_name FROM TBL_PERSON WHERE (ID = ?)
> bind => [1]
> [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-11-24 12:01:12.771--ClientSession(1084235622)--Connection(819605412)--UPDATE TBL_PERSON SET first_name = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
> bind => [Update Name, 1]

Whereas for Hibernate, the changes are not commited to db unless a save() is called.
I am aware that a if a function is tagged with @Transactional, we do not need to call save() as it will auto commit the changes. However, currently it is tagged only in the next method called.

Any possible causes for this? Could it be due to incorrect configuration?

Comment: Hibernate acts the same and is a result of the open session in view pattern. Disable that. Also why change from Hibernate to EclipseLink? I found Hibernate magnitudes better than EclipseLink. Finally remove the `@Repository` from the interface it doesn't add anything.

Comment: It could be a number of reasons, mostly to do with spring-hibernate outside of the JPA contracts. You've got the Transactional(readOnly = true) set, which is only(mostly) used in Hibernate to return detached instances - spring didn't hook this into other JPA providers as well, and must be associating the existing EntityManager with the later transitions instead of closing it and obtaining a new one - or is committing the read-only transaction for some reason instead of rolling it back.